# timeframe.period add a value

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to add 15 min at the timeframe of the chart.

I have try this but there is a error
*Cannot call 'request.security' with argument 'timeframe'='tp_calc'. An argument of 'simple int' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected*

And if i change to str.tostring, the plot is not good.

```
symbol =""
tp = timeframe.period
tp_calc = timeframe.multiplier + 15


len = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length")
src = close
offset = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = request.security(symbol, tp_calc, (ta.ema(src, len)))

plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Pinecoders reference from here: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#time-dates-and-sessions

```
// ————— Converts current chart timeframe into a float minutes value.
f_tfInMinutes() => 
    _tfInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

float my_time = f_tfInMinutes() + 15
plot(my_time)
```